# SQL server 2000 internal error 8624 in the same code that have been ran for 10 years

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have a legacy SQL server 2000 database running at my office and recently the 10-year code that had had to work for 10 years. Now having the weird problem.
The code is really simple, it is the update statement for 3 fields. However, now when I tried to update one of the fields(ard.Applbatnbr) in this query now, I got the internal error 8624. (Just to be clear again, this code was running for 10 years with no problem)

```
UPDATE Ard 

   SET ard.Applbatnbr ='',ard.ApplAmt=0,ard.CuryApplamt=0 

  FROM wrkrelease w INNER JOIN batch b 
                       ON b.batnbr = w.batnbr 
                    INNER JOIN ardoc ard
                       ON ard.Applbatnbr = b.batnbr
 WHERE b.Module='AR' AND w.Module='AR' 
   AND useraddress =@useraddress 
   AND b.status ='I'
   AND b.editscrnnbr ='08030'
```

This code will return the error message 'Internal SQL server error'

However, when I tried to update only another 2 fields by removing the problem field(ard.Applbatnbr) I could process the update with no error.

```
UPDATE Ard 

   SET ard.ApplAmt=0,ard.CuryApplamt=0 

  FROM wrkrelease w INNER JOIN batch b 
                       ON b.batnbr = w.batnbr 
                    INNER JOIN ardoc ard
                       ON ard.Applbatnbr = b.batnbr
 WHERE b.Module='AR' AND w.Module='AR' 
   AND useraddress =@useraddress 
   AND b.status ='I'
   AND b.editscrnnbr ='08030'
```

I tried to update this field "ard.Applbatnbr" with another query in the table directly with no join with another 2 tables. like the example below, I did not get any error as well.

`update ardoc set ard.Applbatnbr = '' where batnbr = 'xxxxx'`

The internal error will be shown whenever I have this field "ard.Applbatnbr" update and join those 3 (wrkrelease, batch, ardoc) tables at the same time.

I also tried to run this query in another database that contains the same table structure and the query will work just fine. So I am completely lost. Is there anything I miss? Please help.

Comment: Have you tried running something like `DBCC CHECKDB`? It could be that your 10 year old database is having some issues

Comment: My guess is a foreign key/index is corrupt.  Check the relationships between the table and try regenerating the indexes